# Fiona Throws Error Null layer: ''

Tags: python, kml, fiona

I have a file Mapp.kml (1 of 5). I am trying to read this file into Python through Fiona.

I keep getting an error

> ValueError: Null layer: ''

Things I have tried:

```
polygon_1 = gpd.read_file('../MAPP.kml', driver='KML')
```

and

```
polygon_1 = gpd.read_file('../MAPP.kml', driver='KML',layer = 'Maps')
```